# Getting a the current instance of the "Parent" view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have a embeded view, inside another view, how would i get the current instance of the parents viewController in the Childs viewController, need it to call a method on the parent, on the current instance.

This is how i current call the method on the parent, this allocates a new instance.

```
CalendarMonthViewParent *controller = [[CalendarMonthViewParent alloc] init];
[controller callChildChange];
```

I get "No visible interface declares "callChildChange", if i call it like this:

```
[self.parentViewController callChildChange];
```

**EDIT 1:**

CalendarMonthViewParent.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CalendarMonthViewParent : UIViewController

-(void) callChildChange;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *skemaNavigationItem;

@end
```

CalendarMonthViewParent.m

```
- (void)callChildChange { // this is called from the child

   UINavigationItem *navBar = [self skemaNavigationItem];
   NSLog(@"logging navItem: %@", navBar); // this logs null when called from the child, since its called on a new instance and not the old one, if i call this from the parent directly, it is not null

}
```

CalendarMonthViewChild.m

```
- (void) calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView*)monthView didSelectDate:(NSDate*)date{
NSLog(@"Date Selected: %@",date);

...

CalendarMonthViewParent *controller = [[CalendarMonthViewParent alloc] init];
[controller callChildChange]; // this calls it on a new instance, i need it to call it on the existing instance

...

}
```

Comment: Is `self.parentViewController` not working?

Comment: How do you put your childViewControoler into parentViewController? I.e. how are they connected?

Comment: Simple embed in a view container on ViewDidLoad set up via storyboard

Comment: You mean, in parentViewController's viewDidLoad you do something like [self.view addSubview:[childViewController view]] ?
And you have childViewController as ivar in your parentViewController?

Comment: Not programmaticly i am afraid, i just dragged the view in to the container, so its added as "Triggered Segues" viewDidLoad -> embed child view controller

Comment: The problem is, I used to do everything programmatically :) Anyway, how do you implement your callChildChange method?

Comment: Heh, well how would i embed the view in to a container programmatically ? :) Il post all the relevant code

Comment: But your code is [controller callChildChange]; -> there must be callChildChange implementation somewhere? To be honest, I never worked with InterfaceBuilder and Storyboards, always programmatically.
UPD: ah OK, I see.

Comment: The child view is added via storyboard, il just try to add it programmticaly, and then i assume i just store the instance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by taking the lines commented 1 and 3 from the "Custom Container ViewController - [Adding and Removing a Child](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW13)" example listing:

```
- (void) displayContentController: (UIViewController*) content;
{
   [self addChildViewController:content];                 // 1
   content.view.frame = [self frameForContentController]; // 2
   [self.view addSubview:self.currentClientView];
   [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];          // 3
}
```

and putting them into the prepareForSegue:sender: for the container controller class into which a view controller was embedded in the storyboard.

thus

```
 NDOMasterViewController *viewController = (NDOMasterViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
    [self addChildViewController:viewController];                 // 1
    [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];          // 3
```

Now inside the embedded view controller I can use self.parentViewController.

Answer (score 3):

Just call `self.parentViewController` in the child `ViewController`

Comment: What does `self.parentViewController` return? it is probably of a different class than `CalendarMonthViewParent`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, you are trying to get parentViewController's instance only to send the message "Hello, I'm your childViewController, and I was changed".

Rather than doing that, I recommend you to implement a `ChildViewControllerDelegate` protocol, and change your ParentViewController so it will conform to that protocol.

Then, in your childViewController you'll need to call something like `[delegate childViewControllerChanged:self];`

But I don't know how to set delegate for the view controller, that was added not programmatically. If you know how - good luck :)